# How to place custom scrollbar buttons one by one left/right?

Tags: html, css

### Problem

Scroll bars are implemented with images.
I made the scroll bar like this with reference to the following.
With reference to the following, the scroll bar has become like this now.
[image: like this]
Reference site:
[I want to make knob of input range an image - StackOverflowJP](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/19182/input-range%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A4%E3%81%BE%E3%81%BF%E3%82%92%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84) (I'm sorry at the Japanese site..)
[Implement scrollbar-button - JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/burkybang/1z7vgfpt/)

▼ I want to do this:
[image: this]

- specify the width & height size of the `scrollbar`
- `scrollbar-button` left / right one by one
- position `scrollbar` at a distance away from target

---

### Code

▼ Probably is not properly displayed unless it's a `webkit` browser (eg Chrome etc.)

```css
html {font-size: 62.5%;}

#thumb-wrap {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 12.4rem;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  writing-mode: bt-lr;    /* IE */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
 }
#thumb-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 33.2rem;
 }
#thumb-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 30.1rem;
  background: url("https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228080150.png");
 }
#thumb-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.3rem;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
 }
#thumb-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  width: 1.6rem;
  height: 1.6rem;
 }
#thumb-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start {
  display: block;
 }
#thumb-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:decrement {
  width: 1.6rem;
  height: 1.6rem;
  background: url("https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228080158.png") no-repeat center center;
 }
#thumb-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end {
  display: block;
 }
#thumb-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:increment {
  width: 1.6rem;
  height: 1.6rem;
  background: url("https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228080155.png") no-repeat center center;
 }
#thumb-wrap ul {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
 }
#thumb-wrap li {
  display: inline-block;
 }
#thumb-wrap li:first-child {
  margin-left: 3rem;
 }
#thumb-wrap li:last-child {
  margin-right: 3rem;
 }
#thumb-wrap li + li {
  margin-left: 3rem;
 }
```

```html
<div id="thumb-wrap">
   <ul>
     <li>
       <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075715.png" alt="あ=a" /></a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075712.png" alt="い=b" /></a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075710.png" alt="う=c" /></a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075706.png" alt="え=d" /></a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075704.png" alt="お=e" /></a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075810.png" alt="か=f" /></a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075807.png" alt="き=g" /></a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075805.png" alt="く=h" /></a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075802.png" alt="け=i" /></a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075759.png" alt="こ=j" /></a>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: The scrollbar is usually pretty strictly displayed as the browser wants it. For most browsers you cannot modify much on the native one. My recommendation is to hide it completely with css and them implement a custom one with JavaScript.

Comment: @JensV Oh JavaScript!
As for JavaScript I'm a true beginner and I still feels difficult, So I'll try it if I can't do it by CSS. Thanks for the advice! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I could do using CSS and JS.  It uses a range input as a slider

```
<input id="slider" type="range" min="1" max='100' value="0" step="1">
```

with the value representing the percentage of the view to scroll left :)

I could not find a pure-CSS solution

**See demo below**

```js
$(function() {
   // this just reads the initial value of the input and displays it on the span
  $("#position").text($("#slider").val());

   // this is an event handler.  The the slider changes it executes the function within
  $("#slider").on('change input', function() {

    // display the input value on the span (updates it)
    $("#position").text($(this).val());
    
    // calculate the new left position of the displayDiv by getting a percentage of the width
    // of the parent.
    // the idea here is that the range has a min value of 1 and a max of 100, they represent 
    // a percentage of pixels to move right or left.  So if I move the input/range slider to
    // have a value of 10, I mean to slide the displayDiv 10%.     
    // this means, 10% of the width of the wrapper (350px) which is 35px;
    var posLeft = $(this).val() * $("#wrapper").width() / 100;
    
    // set the new left position of the displayDiv with the calculated value
    $("#displayDiv li").css('left', -posLeft);
  });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  white-space: no-wrap;
}

.nav {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 210px;
  columns: 100px 100;
  column-gap: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  
}

input['range'] {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
}

#sliderDiv {
  text-align: center;
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul id="displayDiv" class="nav">
    <li>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/200" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/200" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/200" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/200" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/200" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/200" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/200" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/200" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/200" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="sliderDiv">
  <input id="slider" type="range" min="1" max='100' value="0" step="1">
</div>
Position: <span id="position"></span> %
```

Comment: Thank you! x)
That's a good idea!
I also substituted it and moved it, but `input range` and `display` did not move in conjunction with each other.. :'(

If you don’t mind, can you tell me the point with comments ( /**/ ) etc?

Comment: @POP I added some comments to the code, I hope it helps

Comment: Wow, thank you very much!
I will try again tomorrow. Thank you :)

Comment: By the way, what happens when I do it with my code?
I tried it as far as I could, but it did not work because `padding` and right blanks were made.. What I was trying: [this](https://jsfiddle.net/e2rf8x4L/)

Comment: @POP I’ll have a look and get back to you